# Extract image thumbnail from data

Tags: ios, macos

I'm using `CGImageSource` to read Exif (and other) data of image file. Some image files are embedded with their own thumbnail image (used for file icon).
I know I can extract a file icon using `NSWorkspace.shared.icon(forFile:)`, but I'm already holding a `CGImageSource` ref, (and not sure of the cost of `icon(forFile:)` in performance).

Sure I can use the `CGImageSourceCreateThumbnailAtIndex(..` to *generate* a thumbnail, but it would be more efficient to just fetch it (if it exists).

A '*you cannot do that*' answer is also a good answer, (then I can go with plan B).